# Merging two objects in javascript without overwriting users progress in a game

Tags: javascript, jquery

Background: Making a little incremental/idle game and It's got auto clickers and upgrades etc and I'm saving the data in localStorage. At the minute I've got the data stored in an object and I want to be able to add more clickers/upgrades without having to reset the users progress. Here is currently how it is (hopefully not too buggy) - http://johnth.com/

I have an object defined as user which is like a template so when the user first loads the website if there's no local storage it will save user and then the next time they visit it will be loaded into a variable called x and melons and melons per second will be filled with data. Say if I added an upgrade to the melons section then it would be undefined if I tried loading it in so I need to merge the x (which has the users progress) and user (which has the new upgrades). I don't really know the best way to go about this I'm aware of jQuery's `.extend` and `Object.assign` and I can't really figure out how to do it.

```
var user = {
  "name": "",
  "stats": {
    "click": 1,
    "level": 1,
    "xp": 0,
    "melons": 0,
    "mps": 0,
  },
  "upgrades": {
    "melons": {
      "mash": {
        "name": "Mash - 1MPS",
        "cost": 50,
        "value": 1,
        "owned": 0,
        "scale": costScaling
      },
      "masher": {
        "name": "Masher - 5MPS",
        "cost": 500,
        "value": 5,
        "owned": 0,
        "scale": costScaling
      },
      "mashing": {
        "name": "Mashing - 25MPS",
        "cost": 2500,
        "value": 25,
        "owned": 0,
        "scale": costScaling
      },
      "mashmonster": {
        "name": "MashMonster - 100MPS",
        "cost": 250000,
        "value": 100,
        "owned": 0,
        "scale": costScaling
      }
    },
    "other": {
      "click": {
        "name": "Double Clicks",
        "cost": 1000,
        "value": 1,
        "owned": 0,
        "scale": costScaling
      },
      "a30secboost": {
        "name": "30 Second Boost - 2.5x MPS",
        "cost": 25000,
        "value": 2.5,
        "owned": 0,
        "scale": costScaling
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you create a fiddle or something and reduce the data - your question seems quite simple so maybe make up smaller objects and create a snippet of some sort and explain from there

Comment: @DarrenSweeney yeah I'll do that now

Comment: @DarrenSweeney https://jsfiddle.net/xo40u4Lu/ I have explained it to the best of my ability but if you need anymore info I'll try my best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need a recursive version of `$.extend` and `Object.assign` that recursively merges values of two objects. Fortunately, Lodash has such the function you need.

Check out lodash's [merge](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#merge). It enables you to overwrite values that are in the same key "path", or add on if they don't already exist in the first object.

For example:

```
var foo = {
  a: {
    b: 1
  },
  c: 2
}

var bar = {
  a: {
    b: 2
  },
  d: 3
}

console.log(_.merge(foo, bar)) =>

{
  a: {
    b: 2 // overwritten by value in bar
  },
  c: 2,
  d: 3   // added by bar
}
```

Comment: How did it go? Was it helpful?

Comment: It looks like what I needed, still trying to implement it.